# How to create a Registration Form using Google Form with a QR code generated that will Email/Send to the User after Submission

Tags: email, google-sheets, registration, qr-code, google-forms

Hi I would like to create a Registration Form where there is a QR Code system generated that also emailed to the User automatically after submission. What actually i'm trying to do is to create a system, when the user or a guest is register to my Registration form made of google form he/she will get his/her QR code generated in his mail.
What i want to know is How can i make this possible using a Google Form, also the spreadsheet where the logs or the names stored. I know that google Spreadsheet can use QR code generator but how can it sends or email the qr code generated in each name automatically to the corresponding email who registered.

Comment: i actually don't tried anything yet, but I did create a registration form that required their email for the successful registration, i want this form to function as a user registered it will generate a QR code, then it sends to their email. I know it's possible because i saw this kind of system generated somewhere but i don't remember.So I tried to search anywhere even from youtube wondering if there's a tutorial, but i haven't seen anything to function that sends the QR code automatically after a successful submission. I hope someone tell me what i need to create this kind of System Gnrated.

Comment: btw this system im trying to function as a user registered it will generate a Qr code and will send to the user after a successful submission is made of Google Form. I watched a tutorial from youtube alike from what i want to happen in registration form made in google form but this system is functioning like this, after a user registered then this responder can be view in google spreadsheet then what the admin of this form did is applied a QR code formula in the spreadsheet manually or like an excel draggin down then sends the generated QR code manually to the respondents corresponding email.